# Google Sheets change cell background if cell matches another cell from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have tried using the conditional formatting custom formula on this, but no such luck.  Basically, in the "Location" sheet if the text in a cell in column A matches the text in a cell in Sheet "Jobs" column A, then change the background to blue.

In the Location tab/sheet, I tried a custom formula to compare the value to the value of column A in the Jobs sheet but keep getting an invalid formula error.

=A2:A="JOBS!A2:A"

Do I need to use a custom script instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use INDIRECT. This will work with two sheets where Sheet1 A2:A is equal to JOBS!A2:A and JOBS!A2:A is not blank.

Apply to Range

A2:A

Custom Formula

```
=AND(A2:A=indirect("JOBS!A2:A"),  A2:A<>"")
```